# C# (or VB): How to modify a class that is serializable

Tags: c#, serialization

I have an class with a number of members. Some members are not needed. I would like to delete the un-needed members from the class definition.

The class is declared as Serializable. I'm concerned previously persisted objects will not deserialize properly. What is the procedure to update the definition of a serializable class? [Serialization (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx) does not discuss the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to remove the members from your class.Instead you can opt out Members by decorating with the [nonserialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx) attribute.Members decorated with nonserialized attribute will not be serialized.

```
[Serializable()]        
public class SimpleObject  {

    //A field that is serialized.
    public int member1;

    // A field that is not serialized.
    [NonSerialized()] public string member5; 

    public SimpleObject() {

        member1 = 11;
        member5 = "hello world!";
    }

}
```

A DeSerialization on a previously persisted object, will save a empty value on the NonSerialized memberfield.
To solve this,you can write your member initialization code on a custom method decorated with the [OnDeserialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx) Attribute.

Comment: What happens when the new code (i.e., fields marked with NonSerialized) encounters an old object that was persisted with the field?

Comment: There will not be any exceptions and you will get a empty value for that field.